How to catch error with Microsoft Graph in C#
I manage to implement Microsoft Graph to retrieve e-mails via the InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication. Everything works fine after some struggles to configure everything via Graph Explorer (which I can't even remember how I did it).
Basically, I'm redirected to the web browser where I'm asked to click on the e-mail I want to use for the authorisation. Nevertheless, I would like to catch when I close the tab or click on the wrong e-mail.
Can someone tell me how to catch the failed authentication? It seems it gets stuck at await user.MailFolders.GetAsync().
var appSettings = _configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");

var tenantId = appSettings["Microsoft Graph:tenant id"];
var clientId = appSettings["Microsoft Graph:client id"];

var redirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost");

var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
{
    TenantId = tenantId,
    ClientId = clientId,
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
};
            
var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

var scopes = new []
{
    "Mail.Read"
};

var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential, scopes);

try
{
    var user = graphServiceClient.Me;

    var mailFolders = await user.MailFolders.GetAsync(); // Gets stuck here even if the authentication fails.

    // ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return;
}


Try this `try
{
var user = graphServiceClient.Me;
var mailFolders = await user.MailFolders.GetAsync();

}
catch (ODataError odataError)
{
Console.WriteLine($"OData Error Message: {odataError.Error.Message}");
Console.WriteLine($"OData Error Code: {odataError.Error.Code}");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Console.WriteLine($"Unexpected Error: {ex.Message}");
}
`

To fetch Mail folders of signed in user, make sure to grant Mail.Read delegated API permission:

Use the below code:
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

var tenantId = "TenantID";
var clientId = "ClientID";
var redirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost");

var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
{
    TenantId = tenantId,
    ClientId = clientId,
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
};

var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);
var scopes = new[] { "Mail.Read" };
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential, scopes);

try
{
    var user = graphServiceClient.Me;

    var mailFoldersResponse = await user.MailFolders.GetAsync();

    var mailFolders = mailFoldersResponse.Value;

    foreach (var folder in mailFolders)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Folder Name: {folder.DisplayName}");
    }
}
catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"OData Error Message: {odataError.Error.Message}");
    Console.WriteLine($"OData Error Code: {odataError.Error.Code}");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Unexpected Error: {ex.Message}");
}

Output:

Make sure to mark the application as Public:

Reference:
List mailFolders - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft
UPDATE: Try the below code
var tenantId = "TenantID";
var clientId = "ClientID";
var redirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost");

var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
{
    TenantId = tenantId,
    ClientId = clientId,
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
};

var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);
var scopes = new[] { "Mail.Read" };
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential, scopes);

try
{
    var user = await graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync();
    var mailFoldersResponse = await graphServiceClient.Me.MailFolders.GetAsync();
    var mailFolders = mailFoldersResponse.Value;

    foreach (var folder in mailFolders)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Folder Name: {folder.DisplayName}");
    }
}
catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Authentication required: " + ex.Message);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Authentication was cancelled by the user.");
}
catch (AuthenticationFailedException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed: " + ex.Message);
}
catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"OData Error Message: {odataError.Error.Message}");
    Console.WriteLine($"OData Error Code: {odataError.Error.Code}");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Unexpected Error: {ex.Message}");
}


Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't answer my question. It does not handle the situation where the popup is closed or an incorrect email address is clicked (I have two email addresses listed, but only one of those is in line with the configuration).

@LudovicWagner Check the updated answer

Thanks for your update, but it doesn't handle the aborted authentication. It still gets stuck at var mailFolders = await user.MailFolders.GetAsync();. Did I misconfigured how Visual Studio is intended to catch error?
